# pushdown automaton give strings over alpha, beta and gamma

Tags: pushdown-automaton

I understand the basics of PDA's but have a question that I have not come across before.The question is:

Consider following PDA M which accepts with final state and empty stack. $M = (K,\Sigma, \Gamma,\delta, q_0, Z_0, F)$, $K = q_0,\Sigma = a,b,c , \Gamma = a,b,c,S,T ,Z_0 = S, F = q_0)$. The transition relation is given by,

$ \delta(q_0, \epsilon, S) = ((q_0, \alpha),(q_0,T))$

$ \delta(q_0, \epsilon, T) = ((q_0, \beta),(q_0,\epsilon))$

$ \delta(q_0, a, a) = ((q_0, \epsilon))$

$ \delta(q_0, b, b) = ((q_0, \gamma))$

$ \delta(q_0, c, c) = ((q_0, \epsilon))$

Give strings $\alpha, \beta, and \gamma over \Gamma$

All questions I have previously seen give transition functions that are more straightforward and dont include $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ so im unsure of what this really means, since they arent part of the input alphabet. When it says give strings over $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ does it mean I should make up my own input string ? and change the transition functions accordingly or what ? Im not quite sure and havent been able to find anything online. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings are not input since they are over the alphabet $\Gamma$. You should just determine what the PDA puts on the stack in the first, second and fourth clause. Is suppose that there is a specific language that this PDA should accept. Then you are to chose the three strings that are to be put on the satck in such a way that the desired language is accepted.

For example, if you put all of them empty, then the language accepted is the one that contains only the empty word.

If you chose $\alpha = \epsilon$ then the two possible transitions of the first clause are identical. If you chose $\alpha = S$ then the first transition essentially does nothing; it just pops an S and puts it back.

So look for the language that your PDA is supposed to accept.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not sure if im clear on what to do still. Are you saying I am meant to assign alpha, beta, gamma a stack input symbol (a,b,c,S,T). and then find the language that is accepted from that ?

Comment: Yes. Depending on your definition of PDA also pushing more than one symbol in one transition might be allowed. Unless there is a "target" language given, this question does not really make sense...

Comment: I have re written the question preety much exactly, as it is on the paper, but I also find it quite hard to understand. Sorry, I just realised the previous question has L(G) equalling (S -> aSc|T), (T -> bTc| \epsilon), which creates a^nb^nb^mc^m. should this be the language im trying to recreate with the PDA.

Comment: based on this i assume α should be ac ? β = bc, and γ = epsilon. but is it possible to put two symbols onto the stack in this way ?

Comment: Your definition should allow pushing more than one symbol on the stack. Otherwise it will never have more than one symbol, because all the transitions pop. Your grammar actually generates a^nb^mc^(m+n), not the language you give. Then you work just as the grammar: \alpha = cSa, \beta cTb, \gamma=\eps. You need the non-terminals in there to get some recursion. Try it for a small example!

Comment: yes its a^nb^mc^(m+n) not what i wrote, I tried out some strings and it definately works. thank you for your help, when I havent seen a type of problem it can be really hard to get my head around the notation and everything even when the problem itself isnt that hard.